# “will probably” use together

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, future-tense

[CRISPR twins might have had their brains inadvertently enhanced](https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEEYL9X6l8WXSGOlOHi2TdigqFggEKg0IACoGCAowof8GMMBfMJbW8wU?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen)

> “The simplest interpretation is that those mutations **will probably**
>   have an impact on cognitive function in the twins,” says Silva.

I think "will" means that will happen, but "probably" means that may happen or maybe not.
Why?

Comment: "would probably" is for hypotheticals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, "will have" is a simple future tense expression. ***Probably*** is an adverb modifying the verb *have*. This is exactly the same as "I probably have enough money" in the present, or "he probably forgot to phone" in the past.

The tense does not indicate the certainty of a verb. There are modal verbs that affect certainty, such as *could* or *might*, but adverbs can also affect certainty.